# How to find the greater value for a particular key

Tags: linux, shell, unix, duplicates

My data is like:

```
key1 12
key1 14
key1 16
key2 13
key2 14
```

And the output should be like:

```
key1 16
key2 14
```

that is i want the greater value associated with the key.

How to do that using unix commands?

Answer (score 3):

try this one-liner please:

```
awk '{a[$1]=$2>a[$1]?$2:a[$1]}END{for(x in a)print x, a[x]}' file
```

**EDIT**

oops, after I posted this answer, I noticed fedorqui had posted a quite similar one.(3x seconds ealier than me) I just add another one. but **the above awk-oneliner is preferred.**

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2nr file|awk '$1!=t{t=$1;print}'
```

with your data:

```
kent$  echo "key1 12
key1 14
key1 16
key2 13
key2 14"|sort -k1,1 -k2,2nr|awk '$1!=t{t=$1;print}'
key1 16
key2 14
```

Comment: +1 second answer does not use an array and also works with negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this can make it:

```
$ awk '($2 > a[$1]) {a[$1]=$2} END{ for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
key1 16
key2 14
```

It stores the data in the array `a[]`, so the index is the first field and the value is the value. When it finishes reading the file, in `END` it loops through the array and prints the results.

Comment: @PrashanthCm well it is a way to explain that I store the data in an array `a[field]=max_value`. Did it work to you?

Answer (score 0):

Using bash you could use the following script to get what you want:

```
declare -A result
( while read key val; do
    if [ "${result[$key]}" == "" ]; then
      result[$key]=$val;
    elif [ ${result[$key]} -lt $val ]; then
      result[$key]=$val;
    fi;
  done;
  for key in ${!result[@]}; do
    echo "$key ${result[$key]}";
  done
)
```

Note, that the values have to be integers. Otherwise the second if-expression will give an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `sort` twice (not the most efficient way, but it's concise):

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2r file.txt | sort -u -k1,1
```

The first sort sorts first by key, then in reverse order on the second key. The second `sort` outputs only the first line that contains each of the first keys (which, by the first sort, has the largest value).